# Abas com cores diferentes usando css e jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Preciso fazer algumas abas para que seja mostradas informações de acordo com a aba cliclada, o que não sei como fazer é as cores das abas, **elas são de cores diferentes quando clica em cada uma**, como eu poderia fazer isso com css e jquery?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sei se vc já  leu isso https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/ Mas é bom ler

Comment: Edita a sua reposta com o código que vc já tem, ai fica mais fácil pra gente te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar estilos diferentes para cada aba, cada uma com a sua cor.

No exemplo abaixo fiz isso e adicionei `tabindex` para pode usar no CSS `:focus`, e coloquei um escutador jQuery para identificar qual aba foi clicada à partir do seu `tabindex`:

> O interpretador do *snippet* tem um *bug*. Ele inicia o index do `:nth-child` em `0`,
>   quando na verdade seria em `1`.

```js
$('.abas').on('click', function(){
   alert('Aba '+ $(this).attr('tabindex') +' clicada!');
});
```

```css
.abas{
   display: block;
   width: 50px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   text-align: center;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
   float: left;
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: none;
}

.abas:hover,
.abas:focus{
   color: #fff;
}

.abas:nth-child(1){
   border-bottom-color: orange;
}
   .abas:nth-child(1):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(1):focus{
      background: orange;
   }

.abas:nth-child(2){
   border-bottom-color: red;
}
   .abas:nth-child(2):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(2):focus{
      background: red;
   }

.abas:nth-child(3){
   border-bottom-color: purple;
}
   .abas:nth-child(3):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(3):focus{
      background: purple;
   }

.abas:nth-child(4){
   border-bottom-color: blue;
}
   .abas:nth-child(4):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(4):focus{
      background: blue;
   }

.abas:nth-child(5){
   border-bottom-color: green;
}
   .abas:nth-child(5):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(5):focus{
      background: green;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abas" tabindex="1">
   Aba 1
</div>
<div class="abas" tabindex="2">
   Aba 2
</div>
<div class="abas" tabindex="3">
   Aba 3
</div>
<div class="abas" tabindex="4">
   Aba 4
</div>
<div class="abas" tabindex="5">
   Aba 5
</div>
```

Comment: para clicar na aba aparecer uma informação embaixo de cada uma, como eu faria?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado @dvd

Comment: como eu faço para colocar textos diferentes para cada aba? https://jsfiddle.net/x9rtxsv5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x9rtxsv5/1/ olha como fica...

Comment: estava falando assim https://jsfiddle.net/x9rtxsv5/3/ :)

Comment: como faria para já aparecer o conteudo da primeira aba, ao abrir a página?  jsfiddle.net/x9rtxsv5/3

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard Ah tah.. agora entendi... em vez de ficar repetindo os códigos, pode fazer assim pra abreviar: https://jsfiddle.net/x9rtxsv5/4/

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard Abrindo a primeira aba no carregamento da página: https://jsfiddle.net/x9rtxsv5/5/

Comment: e como faria para abrir com a primeira aba aberta?

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard https://jsfiddle.net/x9rtxsv5/5/